# what is correct use pattern of partition in foreachrdd in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming to handle a large set of data. It consists of two steps. First step is to retrieve data and do some basic processing and then Second step is to do the real handling of the data.

```
dstream.foreachRDD ( rdd =>

  //Step 1: retrieve data from web
  val data = rdd.mapPartitions( partition =>
  {
      var finalResult = ArrayBuffer[String]()
      val results = Obatinfromwebandcleaning("path/to/web")
      results.foreach( result => finalResult += result )
      finalResult.iterator
  })

  //Step 2: handle data
  val data_df = sparkSession.read.json(data)
  val res_df = compute(data_df)
  res.write.json("path/to/storage")
)
```

The weird thing is If I just run Step 1 or Step 2 individually, it runs extremely fast. But when I combined them together as above, it becomes 5 times slower. Here is how I did it separately.

```
dstream.mapPartitions( partition =>
      {
          var finalResult = ArrayBuffer[String]()
          val results = Obatinfromwebandcleaning("path/to/web")
          results.foreach( result => finalResult += result )
          finalResult.iterator
      }).saveAsTextFiles("path/to/storage")
```

The above runs fast.

```
dstream.foreachRDD ( rdd =>

      //Step 2: handle data
      val data_df = sparkSession.read.json(rdd)
      val res_df = compute(data_df)
      res.write.json("path/to/storage")
)
```

This also runs fast. 
But when I combined the above two steps together, they run much slower.

So I guess I used the partition and foreachrdd in a wrong way. But just cannot figure out.

Comment: could you compare the stage scheduling in the Spark UI between the independent and the joint runs?

Comment: Also, given that #2 depends on #1, how do you test that step in isolation?

Comment: There is a data source available for test purpose. That is why I can do Step 2.

Comment: Can you try if `dstream.cache().foreachRDD{...#1 + #2}` to see if you get better result. Also can you try using `rdd.sparkSession.read.json()` instead of SparkSession? My guess (Not answer) is that your first action is able to leave the local rdd blocks which is being used for the second action hence making things go faster.

Comment: @Manas rdd does not have sparkSession which means rdd.sparkSession does not exist.  Instead rdd.sparkContext exists. But rdd.sparkContext does not have "read.json" method.